# Funcion que devuelve año de una persona sin tener que especificar el mismo

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy iniciandome en JavaScript y quiero hacer una funcion que devuelva el año de nacimiento de una persona pero tomando el año del servidor (en esta practica, mi notebook). Probe de las siguientes maneras :

```
    function calcularEdad(yearNacimiento) {
    let today = new Date();
    let year = today.getFullYear;
    return year - yearNacimiento; 
}

let edad = calcularEdad(1996);
console.log(edad);
```

En ese caso la consola me arroja como resultado NaN.
Luego probe de esta manera :

```
    function calcularEdad(yearNacimiento) {
    let year = new Date().getYear();
    return year - yearNacimiento; 
}

let edad = calcularEdad(1996);
console.log(edad);
```

Y la consola me arroja como resultado -1876.

Agradezco la amabilidad de la comunidad para responder esta pregunta de principiante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera opcion que pusiste estaba bien, solo te falto colocar el `()` para poder ejecutar la funcion, asi que enrealidad estabas haciendo una operacion aritmetica con una funcion, lo cual porsupuesto da como resultado `NaN`, lo he corregido colocando parentesis a `getFullYear`:

```js
function calcularEdad(yearNacimiento) {
    let today = new Date();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    return year - yearNacimiento; 
}

let edad = calcularEdad(1996);
console.log(edad);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Entonces estaba bien centrado, pero tenia un error de sintaxis nomas. 
Gracias Riven

Answer (score 0):

Estas tomando como parámetro el `prototype` de `date` incorrecto en el segundo caso.

> Esta característica ya no se recomienda. Aunque algunos navegadores aún pueden admitirlo, es posible que ya se haya eliminado de los estándares web relevantes, que se esté descartando o que solo se conserve por motivos de compatibilidad. Evite usarlo y actualice el código existente si es posible;

El `getYear()` método devuelve un año de 2 dígitos o de 4 dígitos:

- Para los años comprendidos entre 1900 y 1999, el valor devuelto por getYear()es el año menos 1900. Por ejemplo, si el año es 1976, el valor devuelto es 76.
- Para años menores de 1900 o mayores de 1999, el valor devuelto por getYear()es el año de cuatro dígitos. Por ejemplo, si el año es 1856, el valor devuelto es 1856. Si el año es 2026, el valor devuelto es 2026.

En tu caso necesitamos el año completo, para ello usaremos el `prototype` de `date` **`getFullYear()`**.

```js
function calcularEdad(yearNacimiento) {
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    return year - yearNacimiento;
}

let edad = calcularEdad(1996);
console.log(edad)
```